# My Router keeps restarting at high speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

this is my first post here.

I have a ZTE 5g MC801a router, had it for 13 months, ever since I signed the contract with ISP. About six weeks ago, the router started restarting on its own, where all the lights would shut down and restart normally ( no red lights). The internet’s speed is usually 300 mbps, and whenever I restart at this speed, it take about an hour or so and then it will restart on its own. However, sometimes it will slow down when it restarts, like instead of starting at 300, it starts on 100, or less. But it will keep restarting after an hour or so, and sometimes, rarely, it will restart within a few mins of starting. However, when it restarts on 40 mbps speed, it doesnt restart, it stays working fine for days, but obviously slower than normal. Here’s a few things I did:

1-Factory Reset

2-Unplugged Ethernet Cables from it

3-Pushed a pin for the bottom button

4-Contacted my ISP for sim refreshing

5-Took the device to maintenance twice, they found nothing wrong with and asked me to check the signal and cell towers

6-Checked for updates on the website (no updates)

Among other things I cant remember now.

My ISP has two departments that I have been contacting, cell towers, and maintenance, and they all been blaming each other. I did place a sim from another service provider, and the router didnt restart for 7 hours, however, it lagged for me after two hours and a half, but the speed was 200, so I restarted it and it worked perfectly for 5 hours afterwards.

Note: My usage is basically me playing online video games, and watching Youtube. There are only 3-4 devices that are connected to the router including my PC, but they’re all phones, I’m the only one with a computer, and they only watch Tiktok or YouTube.

Update: I turned the router on before going to sleep and went to bed. Woke up six hours later found it still running, did a speedtest and it restarted halfway through the test. The router wasnt used by anyone during that time.

Comment: If it keeps restarting on its own and does it quicker the higher the speed my first thought is that it is overheating. Can you (at least temporarily) cool it a bit to see if that helps? E.g place the router in the airflow of a fan or (if it is in the sun) move it to a shaded location.

Comment: Well I have touched the device and it seems warm,  not hot. Plus I have placed another sim from another service provider which was 4g+ and it worked on 200mb speed perfectly for two hours. But once I put the original sim in which is 5g it started to restart again or be slow. 


I have a new update tho, I turned on the device for 6 hours while no one was using it and went to sleep, when I woke up, I did a speedtest and it restarted mid test.

Comment: You additional info  doesn't really change anything it seems. It crashes/reboots/is unstable, under load with 5G, but not (or less so) with 4g+.  I'm still thinking it is overheating. That the outside is just warm doesn't mean anything. It gets a lot hotter inside the housing and even worse inside the chips itself. Quite possible that 5G generates more heat in the internals than 4G does, hence the difference.

Comment: So I have tried it, placed the router infront of an AC that has 20C setting, and can confirm that it didnt work and the router rebooted itself again. I even unplugged it and let it cool down infront of the AC first, before plugging it and testing it.